# Finding position of the first appearance of a string in a list

Tags: python

I just recently started learning python and I'm trying to find the position of my birthday in a list of the first 1mil pi numbers. I've determined that it indeed exists somewhere in the list, but I don't have a clue of how to go about finding the exact position of the first appearance. Could anybody help me out with this?

```
with open(file_name) as file_object:
    lines = file_object.readlines()

pi_string = ""
for line in lines:
    pi_string += line.strip()
    
birthday = input("Enter your birthday in yymmdd:")
if birthday in pi_string:
    print("your birthday is in first mill digits of pi!")
else:
    print("nah bruh")
print(pi_string.count(str(930621)))
```

Comment: I think you need [`find`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) or [`index`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.index)

Answer (score 1):

you can use `enumerate` that allow you to have index and value of a list. Thus, index will be the line where your birthday is

```py
with open(file_name) as file_object:
    lines = file_object.readlines()

birthday = input("Enter your birthday in yymmdd:")
for index, line in enumerate(lines, 1):
    if birthday in line.strip():
       print("your birthday is in first mill digits of pi! line : {}".format(index))
else:
    print("nah bruh")
```

If you want the exact position (not only line number), you can use find

```py
with open(file_name) as file_object:
    lines = file_object.readlines()

pi_string = ""
for line in lines:
    pi_string += line.strip()
    
birthday = input("Enter your birthday in yymmdd:")
pos = pi_string.find(birthday)
if pos:
    print("your birthday is in first mill digits of pi!, position : {}".format(pos))
else:
    print("nah bruh")
```